# RegEx pattern not behaving as wanted

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex pattern

```
[^A-Za-z](email,|help|BGN|won't|go|corner|issues|disconected|We|group|No|send|Bv|connecting|has|Pittsburgh,|Many|(Akustica,|Toluca|cannot|Restarting|they|not|PI2|one|condition|entire|LAN|experincing|bar|Exchange,|server|Are|PA)|OutLook|right|says|Rose|Montalvo|back|computer|are|Jane|thier|Disconnected|Nrd|and/or|network|for|Appears|e-mail|unable|Connected|then|Broadview,|issue|email|shows|available|be|we|exchange|error|address|based|My|Microsoft|received|working|created|receive|impacted|WIFI|through|connection|including|or|IL|outlook|via|facility|Everyone's|servers|Also|message|"The|your|Status|doesn't|service|SI-MBX82.de.bosch.com,|next|appears|"disconnected"|Encryption|eMail/file|today|"Waiting|"send/receive"|but|it|trying|SAP|disconnected|e-mails|this|getting|can|of|connect|Incorrect|manually|is|site|an|folder"|cant|Other|have|in|Receiving|if|Plant|no|SI-MBX80.de.bosch.com|that|when|online|persists."|Customer|administrator|users|update|applications|"Disconnected"|SI-MBX81.de.bosch.com|The|on|lower|Some|It|contact|In|the|having)[^A-Za-z]
```

And applying but it is not able to find `"Jane"` in the sentence

```
 "Issue with eMail/file Encryption Incorrect email address created for Jane Rose Montalvo."
```

While Jane is present in the above pattern that I am using.

What could be the reason?

Comment: When your regex looks like this.. you should consider changing it.

Comment: I formed this regex by joining the substrings formed after split() method (Not all substrings, only those who were less in frequency). Any other way to do this?

Comment: Possibly want to use `\b` [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) rather than `[^A-Za-z]` and also to escape the `.` for such as `de\.bosch\.com` to match a literal dot.

Comment: I used the word boundaries too, but the problem seemed to be due to overlapping of characters mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your regex captures `\s` before and after the word and it is also the matching criteria.

`Hello Jane`

So from this once `Hello` is captured `Jane` is left and it cannot be matched as it has no space before it.You should make it an assert rather than matching one.

Use (?<=[^a-zA-Z]) instead of simple [^a-zA-Z].See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lU7jH1/9

Comment: lookahead will have support in more languages than lookbehind. also alternatives to `^` or `$` should be provided

Comment: @Aprillion it has been tagged as python.It supports lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

Because of overlapping of characters. Just use a capturing group inside lookahead inorder to capture the overlapping characters,

```
(?=[^A-Za-z](email,|help|BGN|won't|go|corner|issues|disconected|We|group|No|send|Bv|connecting|has|Pittsburgh,|Many|(Akustica,|Toluca|cannot|Restarting|they|not|PI2|one|condition|entire|LAN|experincing|bar|Exchange,|server|Are|PA)|OutLook|right|says|Rose|Montalvo|back|computer|are|Jane|thier|Disconnected|Nrd|and/or|network|for|Appears|e-mail|unable|Connected|then|Broadview,|issue|email|shows|available|be|we|exchange|error|address|based|My|Microsoft|received|working|created|receive|impacted|WIFI|through|connection|including|or|IL|outlook|via|facility|Everyone's|servers|Also|message|"The|your|Status|doesn't|service|SI-MBX82\.de\.bosch\.com,|next|appears|"disconnected"|Encryption|eMail/file|today|"Waiting|"send/receive"|but|it|trying|SAP|disconnected|e-mails|this|getting|can|of|connect|Incorrect|manually|is|site|an|folder"|cant|Other|have|in|Receiving|if|Plant|no|SI-MBX80\.de\.bosch\.com|that|when|online|persists\."|Customer|administrator|users|update|applications|"Disconnected"|SI-MBX81\.de\.bosch.com|The|on|lower|Some|It|contact|In|the|having)[^A-Za-z])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oY5nA8/12)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you cannot or do not want to modify your pattern and you have overlapping matches that you want to capture, you can use `re.search` in a loop - moving the starting point for the search to the character just after the beginning of the previous match.

```
#recursive
def foo(s, p, start = 0):
    m = p.search(s, start)
    if not m:
        return ''
    return m.group() + foo(s, p, m.start() + 1)

#iterative
def foo1(s, p):
    result = ''
    m = p.search(s, 0)
    while m:
        result += m.group()
        m = p.search(s, m.start() + 1)
    return result

print foo(s, re.compile(p))
print foo1(s, re.compile(p))

>>> 

 eMail/file  Encryption  Incorrect  email  address  created  for  Jane  Rose  Montalvo.
 eMail/file  Encryption  Incorrect  email  address  created  for  Jane  Rose  Montalvo.
>>>
```

Comment: I like [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jqZ8DWONvX_11-K8) for its visual representation of the regex pattern.